Change the date format in JOLT
In the attached JOLT, I want to change the date format, type conversion and string operation as follows.

Date needs to change into yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format (2024-06-16 23:54:14) from UTC (2024-06-16T23:54:14.711456Z)
The value of WEIGHT code needs to convert into decimal from string
for machinename, needs to get only the name

Can someone please help on this. Thank you
Input JSON
{
  "machine": "26619",
  "mname": "MapRecord[{name=machine_col}]",
  "timestamp": "2024-06-16T23:54:14.711456Z",
  "temp": "16.0",
  "height": "0.151",
  "site": "2343",
  "weight": "0.2955",
  "length": "0.2"
}

JOLT:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "mname": "machinename",
      "timestamp": "Date",
      "temp": {
        "@": "data[0].value",
        "#A2-P1-M1 5cm": "data[0].code"
      },
      "height": {
        "@": "data[1].value",
        "#A1-P1-T1 5cm": "data[1].code"
      },
      "weight": {
        "@": "data[2].value",
        "#WEIGHT": "data[2].code"
      }
    }
  }
]

Expected JSON Output :
{
  "machinename": "machine_col",
  "Date": "2024-06-16 23:54:14",
  "data": [
    {
      "value": "16.0",
      "code": "A2-P1-M1 5cm"
    },
    {
      "value": "0.151",
      "code": "A1-P1-T1 5cm"
    },
    {
      "value": 0.2955,
      "code": "WEIGHT"
    }
  ]
}


You can use the following transformation spec :
[
  { //derive "machinename" and "Date" attributes
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "mname": "=split('name=',@(1,&))",
      "mname_": "=split('}',@(1,mname))",
      "machinename": "=(@(1,mname_[1][0]))",
      "timestamp": "=split('T',@(1,&))",
      "timestamp_": "=join(' ',@(1,timestamp))",
      "timestamp__": "=split('Z',@(1,timestamp_))",
      "Date": "=(@(1,timestamp__[0]))",
      "weight": "=toDouble" //convert to decimal format
    }
  },
  { //form two independent arrays "value" vs. "code"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "machinename|Date": "&",
      "temp": {
        "@": "data.value",
        "#A2-P1-M1 5cm": "data.code"
      },
      "height": {
        "@": "data.value",
        "#A1-P1-T1 5cm": "data.code"
      },
      "weight": {
        "@": "data.value",
        "#WEIGHT": "data.code"
      }
    }
  },
  {//tile the attributes regarding their orders of the elements within the arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[&1].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Hi I have modified your spec by adding few operations before it.
 [
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "weight": "=toDouble",
      "mnameSplit1": "=split('=', @(1,mname))",
      "mnameVar1": "@(1,mnameSplit1[1])",
      "mnameSplit2": "=split('}]', @(1,mnameVar1))",
      "mname": "@(1,mnameSplit2[0])",
      "timestamp": "=split('T',@(1,&))"
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "timestampVar": "=substring(@(1,timestamp[1]),0,8)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "timestamp": "=join(' ',@(1,timestamp[0]),@(1,timestampVar))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "mnameSplit1": "",
      "mnameVar1": "",
      "mnameSplit2": "",
      "mnameVar2": "",
      "timestampVar": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "mname": "machinename",
      "timestamp": "Date",
      "temp": {
        "@": "data[0].value",
        "#A2-P1-M1 5cm": "data[0].code"
      },
      "height": {
        "@": "data[1].value",
        "#A1-P1-T1 5cm": "data[1].code"
      },
      "weight": {
        "@": "data[2].value",
        "#WEIGHT": "data[2].code"
      }
    }
  }
 ]

And Jolt currently don't provide utility to change Date to required format but I have done it through modify-overwrite-beta by splitting with T and joining with empty space and also trimming the values till the length required in your date format.
Hope this helps!
